# Hiding external JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an external JavaScript in my HTML page.  Is there a way to disable linking to or viewing this js file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is not a way to do this.  It's a client-side scripted language...you cannot in any way hide the a script that's running...not from the people you are probably *wanting* to hide it from (people who would go after your script are smarter than the average user most likely).

There are a number of tools available to inspect javascript, [Chrome's tools](http://blog.chromium.org/2009/06/developer-tools-for-google-chrome.html), [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), any traffic sniffer, [javascript unpackers](http://jsunpack.jeek.org/dec/go) (though debate-ably packing/minifying makes the code less "out of the box" usable).

You can *deter* people with the packing/minification, but you cannot prevent them from seeing/figuring out the code.

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot.  If the browser is executing it, users can find a way to view it.

You might consider a Javascript minifier/obfuscator, like [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/), to make the reverse-engineer's job harder.

Comment: I would debate this makes the job *any* harder, it's been at best a marginal slowdown to anything I've tried to see/figure out.  I would suggest the google compiler instead...but since it strips out unused code, it would make it actually *simpler* to figure out as a result of the decreased size/complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Nick Craver is correct (vote it), never the less, usually when having such problems with protected code, I use php to do some of it, this way the JavaScript file will be available, but not "human-readable" since it doesn't do all the necessary work...

Just a tip, despite I'm much more a share share king of guy!